# why box-shadow/border-radius is slow

Tags: html, css, browser

I'm a front-end engineer,while seeking some performance tips,I always see people telling me to remove some *heavy* css properties,such as `box-shadow`,`border-radius`,but I'm curious about why removing these works?
What material should I have to cover to understand(or have a 3000 feet overview) this

Comment: Really? People tell you to remove `border-radius` because it's "slow"? Any examples? What platforms/browsers/etc. are you developing for? How are you measuring this?

Comment: Pretty sure `border-radius` is totally snappy. `box-shadow`, on the other hand...

Comment: These links could be of interest for you: [html5please - border-radius](http://html5please.com/#border-radius) and [Profiling CSS for fun and profit. Optimization notes.](http://perfectionkills.com/profiling-css-for-fun-and-profit-optimization-notes/)

Comment: Rendering `box-shadow` and `border-radius` **together** is slow. `box-shadow` by itself is slow too. `border-radius` is not too bad. Source: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/css-paint-times/ Consequently, I can't vouch for the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Border Radius in css is **graphical rendering proessing.** Graphical Processing such as finding edges then putting curve of required size on edge.

But, Box Shadow and Border Radius both will take some processing as every other css property will take. For modern computers removing such properties may give you an advantage of 1-2 ns. Even if you remove them your browser apply many css properties of its own.

So there is **almost negligible performance gain** on removing Box Shadow etc. You need to improve programming logic and graphics to improve performance rather than removing css properties

Comment: I'm wondering why so many posts claimed that it works and they got compelling analysis(such as the timeline in chrome dev tools),maybe the browser itself didn't implement these algorithm efficiently?

Comment: can you link any of them here. Or can you explain what performance advantage they gain, how they measure it?

Comment: @Lanston well it is definitely an implementation detail. When features like `box-shadow`, `transformations`, ... where introduced by the vendors, they mostly performed bad, over the time they where optimized. The vendors try do optimize rendering of the pages by using GPU, so the way you can do these effects on GPU is one limiting factors. A blur and masking, would require _more work_ then plain boxes with transparency. Depending on how you combine these and how many you use you can notice performance impacts.